# Interpreting means and standard deviation

Tags: paired-comparisons

How do I interpret means, standard deviations and standard errors in my research work?  for example, I generated a table from SPSS that showed that I had mean 1.60, N=103, Standard deviation of 1.123 and standard error mean of 0.111. what do the values mean?

Answer (score 2):

Like pretty much any statistic, means, standard deviations, and estimates of the standard error have no context-free interpretation. What they mean depends on the data that went into computing them.

For example, if you find that the mean number of children of a sample of American adults is 1.6, this suggests your sample is a little less fecund than usual for Americans. On the other hand, if the mean annual income of the sample is $1.60, you have an exceptionally low-income sample.